# How to see that SL(2,C) is simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I started reading about Lie groups and right now I'm trying understand why $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected. I have shown that $SU(2)$, being diffeomorphic to $S^3$, is simply connected. So my first thought is to construct a deformation retract of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ onto $SU(2)$.

We know that by polar decomposition, every element $g \in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ can be written as $u_g.x_g,$ where $u_g \in SU(2)$ and $x_g$ is a positive semi-definite self-adjoint element of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. And since the polar decomposition is unique, we can immediately define our retraction map as follow $$r : SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow SU(2)$$ $$g \mapsto u_g$$ Let $\iota: SU(2) \hookrightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ be the inclusion map. Now I have trouble constructing a homotopy between $\iota \circ r$ and the identity map on $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ . Any hint?

Another approach I have is to show that $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3 \times M$, where $M$ is a $3-$ dimensional smooth manifold defined by $\left \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4: x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2=1 \right\}$. Again constructing the diffeomorphism is easy, taking advantage of the uniqueness of polar decomposition of $g\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. So to show that $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected we now just need to show that $M$ is simply connected. But I don't see any easy way to prove this is true!

Anyways, to summarize, I have 2 questions:

1. How to show $\iota \circ r$ is homotopic to the identity map on $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?
2. Why is $M$ simply connected?

Any insight/hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Idempotent" does not mean "homotopic to the identity". Something is idempotent when it squares to itself. An inclusion composed with a retraction is actually always idempotent.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question. I meant homotopic to the identity map. But for some reason, I always write down idempotent.

Comment: Showing the map is homotopic to the identity also doesn't technically prove there is a deformation retraction. It just means it is a homotopy equivalence, which would still get you what you want.

Comment: I learned this definition from Bott & Tu. I might be wrong though. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I just looked it up, apparently the definition is not completely standard. What I'm talking about is apparently called a "strong deformation retraction" by some authors and what you are talking about could indeed be called a deformation retraction (but it is not called that by some authors).

Comment: The deformation retract to $SU(2)$ strategy works. The homotopy is given by performing the Gram-Schmidt process smoothly.

Comment: Well, now answering (2.) is easy, $M$ is simply connected because $\text{Sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ is simply connected ;)

Comment: Haha I see the confusion. I just edited the post. 2 questions are the 2 approaches to show SL(2,C) is simply connected.

Comment: Your $M$ is not quite correct - it's disconnected, with a component for $x_1 > 0$ and $x_1 < 0$, and $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is connected. Once you specify $x_1>0$, $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$; this is one of the ways of describing hyperbolic space. (PS: hi Minh!)

Comment: @Mike Hey Mike! Yea, silly me! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I was trying to follow your suggestion but couldn't quite follow through. Sorry for this silly question, but how does the Gram-Schimdt help in this case?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model#History) for the diffeomorphism with $\mathbb R^3$ - the Weierstrass coordinates. Regarding Qiaochu's comment, Gram-Schmidt takes a matrix and gives you a unitary matrix. What you want is turn this into a deformation retraction of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ onto $U(2)$ instead of just a retract. So instead of replacing the second column $v_2$ with $v_2 - \text{proj}_{u_1}(v_2)$, try interpolating between the first and the second in a way that keeps your matrix invertible. (If you want something more explicit, google 'continuous Gram-Schmidt'.)

Comment: A comment because this does not answer the body of the question, but by far the easiest way of seeing that SL(2,C) is simply connected is by observing that the map taking a matrix to its first row turns SL(2,C) into a bundle over C^2-0 with fibre C. This further shows that SL(2,C) is homotopy equivalent to C^2-0, that is, S^3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On 1) What you want to do is use Gram-Schmidt to do this. Consider matrices $(a_1, a_2)$, where the $a_i$ are column vectors. The Gram-Schmidt process replaces this matrix with $\left(u_1 := a_1/\|a_1\|, \frac{a_2-\text{proj}_{u_1}a_2}{\|a_2-\text{proj}_{u_1}a_2\|}\right)$. This is a retract $SL_2(\mathbb C) \to SU(2)$. We want to replace this with a deformation retract. So let's do each of these steps continuously; first consider $f_t(a_1, a_2) = (a_1/\|a_1\|^t, a_2\cdot \|a_1\|^t)$. This remains in $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$, and $f_1(a_1,a_2)$ has a unit vector in the first column. Now consider $g_t(a_1, a_2) = (a_1, a_2-t\text{proj}_{a_1} a_2)$. Because we're just subtracting a scalar multiple of the first column this is again in $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ for all $t$. Concatenating these two maps gives you a homotopy from the identity to the Gram-Schmidt retract $SL_2(\mathbb C) \to SU(2)$.

This is true in absurd generality. First of all, the same argument applies to show that $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ deformation retracts onto $U(n)$, and $SL_n(\mathbb C)$ to $SU(n)$, and the same is true of their real counterparts. But we can do much better than that: the Malcev-Iwasawa theorem says that for any locally compact group $G$, $G$ deformation retracts onto its maximal compact subgroup $K$ (which exists and is unique up to conjugacy). Indeed there is some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $G$ is homeomorphic to $K \times \mathbb R^n$. This includes, in particular, all Lie groups; I seem to remember that in the Lie group case you're actually diffeomorphic to $K \times \mathbb R^n$ but don't remember a reference.

On your second approach: the subset $M = \{x \in \mathbb R^4 \mid x_1^2 - x_2^2-x_3^3 - x_4^2 = 1,  x_1>0\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$, the map being $\mathbb R^3 \to M, x \mapsto (\sqrt{1+\|x\|^2},x)$. These are known as Weierstrass coordinates. Indeed your $M$ is better known as the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic 3-space; if you put the right semi-Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R^4$, then restricting it to $M$ gives you the hyperbolic metric.

Either approach successfully shows that $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is simply connected.